# DirectX, Assimp model loader has mesh crash

Tags: c++, model, directx, mesh, assimp

I'm working on a model loader coded by DirectX 11 and Assimp(VS C++ 2012). It can successfully load some model files now, but there is a new error just like the picture:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ppHNG.png

I had used assimp viewer to check the model file and it didn't show me any error.

So I guess there has some problems on my codes. D:

I have tryed to load another models and found that this problem occured only when I loaded a model which has more then 50K vertices.

Here is my full codes and the model:
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/90323076/mesh%20crash.rar

Can anyone helps me? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Did you try to invert backface culling? If you can see only the missing parts then, you might need to flip those polygon's normals.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I have found out the defect of my codes after I finished a meal lol. I used WORD to store the indices and it caused the overflow. Now I have fixed it. :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out why there would be the error.

Because I used WORD to store the index data, so it overflowed when the indices got more then 65535.

Changing the WORD to UINT had solved the problem!